How to use @supersami/rn-foreground-service only on Android in a React Native app?
I'm currently using the @supersami/rn-foreground-service library in my React Native project, but I'm facing issues when running the app on iOS. Since this library is Android-specific, I want to ensure that it works only on Android without causing any errors or affecting my iOS build.
I'm importing this library in multiple files, and while it works well on Android, I get errors when trying to run the app on iOS.
Here's the way I'm currently using the library:
import ReactNativeForegroundService from '@supersami/rn-foreground-service';

const config = {
  config: {
    alert: true,
    onServiceErrorCallBack: function () {
      console.warn('[ReactNativeForegroundService] onServiceErrorCallBack', arguments);
    },
  }
};

ReactNativeForegroundService.register(config);

Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated, especially solutions that do not require me to add platform checks everywhere when using this library!
Question:

How can I manage the usage of this library so that it works only for Android?

What is the best way to import and use this library across multiple files without causing issues on iOS?


I tried adding the following configuration in my react-native.config.js file to disable the library for iOS:
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    '@supersami/rn-foreground-service': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};

However, this did not resolve the issue.
